# Conversion of function parameter to child class c++

Tags: c++, parameters, implicit-conversion

I have a parent class with a non virtual interface (NVI):

```
class Parent {
private:
    virtual int do_function(void) = 0;
public:
    int function(void);
    virtual ~Parent() {};
}
```

And a child class (actually, I have a lot of child classes, but I want only this one to work this way)

```
class Child : public Parent {
private:
    int _x;
    int do_function(void) { return _x; };
public:
    Child(int x): Parent(), _x(x) {}
    virtual ~Child() {return do_function();};
}
```

And I want to call a function:

```
int myFunction(Parent& x) {
    return x.function();
}
```

using the code

```
int x = 5;
myFunction(x);
```

but not the

```
int myFunction(const Child& x) {
    return x.function();
}
```

which works fine.
Is it possible to do this with implicit conversion of types?

Comment: Hey I added an edit to my solution fwiw, I think that this is not possible. It might take one of the big guns on SO to consider this to say definitively - but hope I helped.

Comment: This is simply not possible to my knowledge. You're asking for *implicit construction*, which is perfectly fine so long as the implication can *end* with the parameter type of the function. Imagine a hundred ChildX derivations of Parent. Without explicitly constructing the type you *intend* all the compiler can go by is the declared parameter type and the potential implied construction passed on the parameter *value*. In short: this simply isn't going to happen without some serious hackery.

Comment: Do you know what hackery exactly I need? Please, give an advice and i will dig deeper

Comment: My suspicion is that "simply isn't going to happen without some serious hackery" is actually a way of saying rethink what you want to do here. Why is it *so* important that you are able to use what amounts to a side effect to create your instances in what is really just a "visually nice" way? Why can't you have either direct constructors called or some indirect method of creating the instances which returns the reference to the Parent?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to implicitly create a Child Object, constructed with x, and then have it passed through to `myFunction( Parent& )`.

You can do `myFunction(Child(x));`

but I think that when you try with the bare `x`, it tries to construct a object : `Parent(x)` and it fails. That isn't what you want anyway because you **do** want an instance of a Child object.

The way that make_pair does something similar is using a templated copy constructor on the object that is being created (pair) which creates an object of the required type(s).

I think that what you want to do can't be done in that way because you want to create the derived class and it isn't going to try to do that because the function signature is `Parent&`.

**edit and alternative solution**
I made a few attempts to create a template based solution to this by adding a templated constructor to the Parent class but it really does boil down to the fact that ultimately you need to invoke a constructor for the derived class.

I think the only sensible solution to this to allow use of the `myFunction(Parent&)` is to use an Indirect method that returns a reference to a Parent after constructing  (temporary?) the child - that of course means you would have many such methods if you have many child classes. I realise that this is not quite as simple as passing in the int (and having it construct and pass in the ref), but it is almost what you want :)